# Join two rows by different ids from a same table

Tags: sql

I would like to join two rows by different ids from a same table.

```
Fruit table:
name:    from_id:   to_id:
Apple    Spain      Italy

Country table:
id:      packaging_type:    packaging_quantity:
Italy    wood box           12
Spain    paper box          18
```

And I would like to get this table:

```
Spain paper box 18 Italy wood box 12
```

And I tried something like this:

```
SELECT a.packaging_type, a.packaging_quantity, b.packaging_type, b.packaging_quantity 
FROM fruit
    inner join country a on a.country.id = fruit.from_id
    inner join country b on b.country.id = fruit.to_id
WHERE fruit.name = 'Apple';
```

But I got an error:

```
ORA-00904: "A"."COUNTRY"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting an alias to the county table in your `INNER JOIN`. You don't need to repeat the table name after the alias `a` or `s`.  Just use `a.id` instead of `a.county.id`.

```
SELECT a.packaging_type, a.packaging_quantity, b.packaging_type, b.packaging_quantity 
FROM fruit
INNER JOIN country a ON a.id = fruit.from_id
INNER JOIN country s ON b.id = fruit.to_id
WHERE fruit.NAME = 'Apple';
```

Additionally, you can use an alias for the `fruit` table if you want to be consistent.

```
SELECT a.packaging_type, a.packaging_quantity, b.packaging_type, b.packaging_quantity 
FROM fruit f
INNER JOIN country a ON a.id = f.from_id
INNER JOIN country s ON b.id = f.to_id
WHERE f.NAME = 'Apple';
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `a.id`, not `a.country.id`.

So, your query will be:

```
SELECT a.packaging_type, a.packaging_quantity, b.packaging_type, b.packaging_quantity 
FROM fruit
    inner join country a on a.id = fruit.from_id
    inner join country s on b.id = fruit.to_id
WHERE fruit.name = 'Apple';
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.country.id` should be `a.id`

`b.country.id` should be `b.id`